# How can I have a different config class for each iOS developer?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm looking for a good way to let each developer have a different config (e.g. server URLs, config flags) that works well with Objective-C and git and supports a default config. One idea is to have two plist files: one checked into git with all the defaults and one that is not checked in and contains custom overrides.

It'd be nice to have more flexibility than a static plist so I started thinking about conditionally loaded classes. Like:

```objc
+ (NSDictionary *)config
{
    NSMutableDictionary *defaults = ...;
    # if DeveloperConfig.h+m exist
      // DeveloperConfig can run arbitrary code to override fields
      [defaults addEntriesFromDictionary: [DeveloperConfig config]];
    # endif
    return defaults;
}
```

Is there a recommended solution for this kind of per-dev configuration?

Answer (score 0):

I will do this way that `MyConfigManager` does not depends on anything. [`+[load]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSObject/load) is used to register configs which will be called by runtime on startup.

```
@implementation MyConfigManager

static NSMutableDictionary *defaults;

+ (NSMutableDictionary *)mutableDefaults
{
    static dispatch_once_t pred;
    dispatch_once(&pred, ^{
        defaults = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    });
    return defaults;
}

+ (void)addDefaults:(NSDictionary *)dict
{
    [[self mutableDefautls] addEntriesFromDictionary:dict];
}

+ (NSDictionary *)config
{
    return [self mutableDefaults];
}

@end

@implementation DeveloperConfig 

+ (void)load
{
    [MyConfigManager addDefaults:@{@"key":@"value"}];
}

@end
```

you don't even need a new class because `load` is called for every categories

```
@interface MyConfigManager (DeveloperConfig)
@end
@implementation MyConfigManager (DeveloperConfig)
+ (void)load
{
    [self addDefaults:@{@"key":@"value"}];
}
@end
```